# Linux grep command with relevant values as output

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Content:

```
1. Name : Jack
   Address : Toronto
   Age : 21
2. Name : Mitchelle
   Address : Newyork
   Age : 67
3. Name : John
   Address : Toronto
   Age : 33
```

Command `grep Toronto` gives me

```
Address : Toronto
Address : Toronto
```

Expected Result:

```
1. Name : Jack
   Address : Toronto
   Age : 21
3. Name : John
   Address : Toronto
   Age : 33
```

Comment: Are you asking "how can I get the whole address block instead of just the line"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you have one line of leading and one line of trailing context you care about, so `grep -C1 Toronto input` should do it.